# FCM Messaging in both library and main app simultaneously

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am having an odd problem. I am integrating a library that uses FCM for registration. However in my own app I also require FCM to retrieve some messages. However, it does not seem like I can have the same app registered to receive messages from both channels (different Server API ID's). The "outer" app seems to override the inner library with its google-services.json

Question: is it possible to accept FCM messages to both the included library and main application at the same time, using two different API keys?

Comment: Which library are you using? It would help in this case. You might be able to do its stuff manually but as far as I know an app cannot be associated with multiple FCM instances.

Comment: Custom library written by somebody else. So in fact the library has its own FirebaseMessagingService and google-services.json

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the way you retrieve informations via FCM is correct. Seems like a bad practice.

You can use [manifest merger](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge) that can replace or override [meta-data elements](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element).

```
  <meta-data 
     android:name="fcm_key"
     android:value="YOUR_KEY"
     tools:node="replace" />
```

To read meta-data in manifest

```
try {
   ApplicationInfo ai = 
   getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(activity.getPackageName(), 
   PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
   Bundle bundle = ai.metaData;
   String myApiKey = bundle.getString("fcm_key");
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
   Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load meta-data, NameNotFound: " + 
   e.getMessage());
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
   Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load meta-data, NullPointer: " + e.getMessage());          
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will help as the FCM info is not included in the manifest